# Calculating last week's data does not work

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with a date column to identify the most recent date (DayDate), and an added column with last week's date (Prev7DayDate). For some reason, my Measure does not work and displays blank value when I want to calculate previous week's total:

TotPrevWk =
VAR latest_prev_wk_date = CALCULATE(MAX('tblA'[Prev7DayDate]), ALLSELECTED('tblA'))

RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM('tblA'[TotACs]), FILTER('tblA',  'tblA'[DayDate] = latest_prev_wk_date && 'tblA'[P]="NO"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `ALL` to return the full table outside of what is filtered. Note the `ALL` in the FILTER below.

```
TotPrevWk =
  VAR latest_prev_wk_date = CALCULATE(MAX('tblA'[Prev7DayDate]), ALLSELECTED('tblA'))

  RETURN CALCULATE(SUM('tblA'[TotACs]), FILTER(ALL('tblA'), 'tblA'[DayDate] = latest_prev_wk_date && 'tblA'[P]="NO"))
```

Comment: That worked. I looked at this a hundred times and couldn't see that. Thank you!